# Excel 2007: Editing a date value deletes the date format

Tags: excel

In an Excel 2007 spreadsheet when I edit a date value the date format of the cell is deleted and I cannot re-apply it with the toolbar options, format > format cells > number > date.

Prior to editing the date value the cell is displayed in the formula bar as 2017/07/15 (for example) but after an edit it displays as ^2017/07/26.

The onset of the problem was sudden and it affects all my Excel 2007 spreadsheets, old and newly created.

I have Goggled the problem and posted a question in MS Forums but without result.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Additional Information - Update Oct 3**

I have found a January 6, 2016 Stack Overflow question about Excel 2013 date format changes caused by editing and one of the answers seems to be relevant to my question. The cells I am attempting to edit have typed (non-formula) dates in them.

**Quote from [Date Format changes when editing a cell in Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638506/date-format-changes-when-editing-a-cell-in-excel-2013)**

**Answer by Jeeped**

… When you edit a cell with a typed (non-formula) date, you are editing the Range.Formula property which in this case is the same as the Range.Value property. The displayed (formatted) date is the Range.Text property. The Range.Formula is the same as that which is seen in the formula bar and the stored format for a typed date is taken from the computer system's regional Short Date setting. The Range.Text property is subject to a formatting mask that changes the way the Range.Value is displayed. Consider it an overlay of the actual value; e.g. if you want to change something, change the something, not a picture of the something.

If you were allowed to edit the displayed text, you would never be able to edit a formula because the values being edited would always be the formula's result (formatted appropriately) and not the formula itself.

If this is really mission critical or just obsessively annoying, change your computer system's Short Date to dd-mm-yyyy and Excel will use that as the base Range.Formula property.

**End of quote**

This quote gives links to the Microsoft Dev Center ,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-formula-property-excel

I am a basic user of Excel and assuming the above information can be used to solve my editing problem then my problem now becomes how do I use this information?

It is less pressing, but I am also curious about why an editing feature I had been using for a long time suddenly stopped working.

---

**Problem Fixed – Update Oct 20**

@a-burge: Thanks for taking an interest in this problem but I have fixed the problem so I am answering my own question.

I use Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 and Microsoft Office 2007 SP3 which have always been updated automatically through Windows 7 > start > control panel > windows update.

The sequence of selections, Windows 7 > start > control panel > region and language, leads to a page with tabs that include a "formats" tab and a "location" tab. Under the former the language setting was "English (New Zealand)" and under the latter the location setting was  "New Zealand".

The problem was fixed by changing the language setting to "English (United States)". The location setting was left unchanged.

This fixes the problem but I do not understand how a language setting in the control panel of Windows 7 can have the effect it does on editing a date in an Excel 2007 spreadsheet?

I think a family member who also uses the computer must have changed the language setting which would account for the sudden onset of the problem and its simple solution.

This is not the first time I have had a problem caused by a language setting in a Microsoft product. In Word 2007 the autocorrect option that I use to expand abbreviations when writing may suddenly stop working. This is caused by the variant of English changing from one part of the document to another. The solution is Word 2007 > select all > set language but that may need to be repeated several times in one document depending on the editing.

These problems raise the question of why Microsoft provides 16 variants of English in Windows 7 when the differences between them are trivial. It even provides English(Australia) and English(New Zealand) and English(United Kingdom) which is an absurd level of redundancy.

Comment: It's likely that Excel reads the cell as text but once you have edited and confirmed by enter then it re-evaluates the cell value, now as date. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @a-burge.   Apologies for the delay in responding. I don't understand your comment because what happens seems to be the reverse. Initially the cell contains a date with a date format but after editing the date the date format is replaced by what seems to be a text format and I cannot re-apply the date format.

Comment: guess we're all busy :) Can you add three screenshots? 1) cell before, 2) cell having pressed F2 (edit formula mode) and 3) cell after pressing enter?